# Is there any way to replace or silence the camera shutter sound in android?

Tags: android, audio, camera

I'd like to replace the shutter sound (the sound the camera makes when snapping a photo) with something else in code.  I was hoping it would be like ringtones or notifications, but I don't see anything anywhere other about it.  I've seen code to silence the phone right before taking the pic, and unsilencing it right after, but I'd prefer to replace the sound with another mp3 or ogg.

Understand if you have a rooted phone, you can replace the file.  This is not a solution for my app.

Just in my app. Idea would be to set it, then unset it. Funny how after you type something out, re-read it, it helps think of it from a different perspective. I've used the code below to shut down the audio service, and I play my sound right before. Works as a great workaround. Perhaps someday, we'll be able to set it.

```
   AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just in my app. Idea would be to set it, then unset it. Funny how after you type something out, re-read it, it helps think of it from a different perspective.  I've used the code 'code' AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);     mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true); to shut down the audio service, but play my sound right before.  Works as a great workaround.  Perhaps someday, we'll be able to set it.

Comment: @MWMWM Why don't you post that as an answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: Depending on where in the world you are, a camera is legally required to make a shutter sound, e.g. Japan. I don't know how Android determines how to trigger this behavior (device language, physical location, country of purchase), but if it does there's no way to silence the shutter sound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `Camera` object, you can supply a `Camera.ShutterCallback` and play whatever you want.

If you are using an `Intent` to launch another app to take the picture, that app gets to choose what it plays when the picture is taken.

Your mute-the-audio solution is user-hostile, as if there is anything else that needs to play a system sound during that period of time, the user won't hear it.

Comment: It may be user hostile, but on some phones and even the Android emulator it appears that the ShutterCallback does not disable the default shutter click sound.  There doesn't seem to be another way around it.  Could google have forced the camera sound because of [legal concers](http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-06/msg00370.html)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me. i do nothing in my shuttercallback, but the sound is still played.

Comment: Doesn't work in android Pie(9). Please help me if you know how to mute in Pie(9).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the data from the preview callback using a function to save it at a picture on some type of trigger such as a button, using onclick listener. you could compress the image to jpeg or png. In this way, there no shutterCallback to be implemented. and therefore you can play any sound you whant or none when taking a picture.