# How to disable shutter camera sound programmatically

Tags: android, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anyway to replace or silence the camera shutter sound in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289481/is-there-anyway-to-replace-or-silence-the-camera-shutter-sound-in-android)

How to disable camera shutter sound programmatically, it is always making sound when I take pictures, I use surffaceview.

Comment: :-) https://market.android.com/details?id=com.blundell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to the Matt Ball's comment and CommonsWare's answer in the other question:

I realized that there are a phones out there which play the shutter sound on their own. In this case, it seems to not be possible to disable the shutter sound.

Comment: it is possible it works but with the same code sometimes programagically it doesn't :)